# When presenting a WKInterfaceController, how can I change the color of the title used to dismiss the controller?

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

In my watch app, after presenting a controller with `presentControllerWithNames:contexts:`, is it possible to change the color of the title in the status bar? For example, in Apple's WatchKit Catalogue sample they have a controller they present modally with "Dismiss" set as the title. In storyboard, the title for this controller appears to have the global tint applied to it, but when running the app in the simulator, the color defaults to white.

If possible, how can I make a presented WatchKit controller respect the global tint color?

edit: Attaching a screenshot for clarity.[image: Apple Watch simulator compared to storyboard interface controller]

Comment: Is this working on iOS11? xcode 9.2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, Global Tint is the answer.

1. go to storyboard file
2. select the interface controller desired to be colored
3. click 'Utilities'
4. click 'File Inspector'
5. Find 'Global Tint', then use 'RGB sliders' under 2nd Tab of the Color pane

Comment: -1 Actually, that's how it SHOULD work, but it doesn't. The OP specifically says he's set the global tint and it shows up everywhere except for the controllers that are presented modally. I'm having the same problem and this answer is not correct. It SHOULD be, but it isn't.

Comment: Worked for me. I am using XCode 7  GM Seed.

Comment: @HamzaAzad, have you seen this work on device? I haven't been doing any development for the watch lately, so I haven't been keeping up with this.

Comment: This works. But do you know how to change the clock color as well? In my watchsim, only the title color changed, but not clock and back arrow.

Comment: This still doesn't work in Xcode 14.3.1 for a modally presented `WKInterfaceController` via `presentControllerWithName:context:`. The title is always white and doesn't use the global tint color as set in Storyboard for the interface controller.

Answer (score 8):

With the current WatchKit SDK, the global tint color does not apply on the WKInterfaceControllers title that are presented modally. I am not sure if this is a bug in the beta version or a feature... I hope Apple will fix this.

Comment: I try to do the same thing. Do you know if it still doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the global tint color. You can change the global color in the "Show the File Inspector" Storyboard.

Sorry I don't have the 10 reputation points required to post a screenshot. ^^

Comment: -1 Actually, that's how it SHOULD work, but it doesn't. The OP specifically says he's set the global tint and it shows up everywhere except for the controllers that are presented modally. I'm having the same problem and this answer is not correct. It SHOULD be, but it isn't.

Comment: Still seems to not set the color in a modal scene